# Error happening randomly when using goroutines WaitingGroup

Tags: asynchronous, go

I have a handler which contains two goroutines. The handler is executed every 10 seconds by the frontend. Once called, the goroutines send a GET http request to an external API. For some reason, sometimes (not often) I randomly get the following error in any of the goroutines (seems that the external API refuses the request).

StatusCode:408

> *panic:read tcp 192.168.1.106:62598->80.243.175.58:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. goroutine
>   8280 [running]:
>   Monitoring/monitoring-v2-goAPI/services.GetNodeCpuLimits.func2(0x815ba0,
>   0xc04231a1c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc042158240, 0x14, 0x0, 0x0, ...)*

When this happens the panic(err) is triggered and my application terminates. This error is happening since I rebuilt the handler in an asynchronous way to improve speed (before the requests were just synchronous).

I would like to know if im doing anything wrong. And if not, how can I handle this? I cant afford the application to terminate.

**Code**

```
   func TestFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        c := make(chan NgxJSON)
        wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

        var queryParams QueryParams
        _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&queryParams)
        fmt.Println("- queryParams ->", queryParams)

        wg.Add(1)
        go func(queryParams QueryParams, c chan NgxJSON, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            defer wg.Done()

            req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", APIURL1+queryParams.Param1, nil)


            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            client := &http.Client{}
            resp, err := client.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)   //<-- Error triggers here!!
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()


            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) 

            var response Response
            json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(body)), &response)


            //DO THINGS

            c <- ngxJSON

        }(queryParams, c, wg)

        wg.Add(1)
        go func(queryParams QueryParams, c chan NgxJSON, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            defer wg.Done()
            req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", APIURL2+APIURL2+queryParams.Param2, nil)

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err) 
                return
            }

            client := &http.Client{}
            resp, err := client.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err) //<-- Error triggers here!!
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()



            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

            var response Response
            json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(body)), &response)


           //DO THINGS

                c <- ngxJSON

            }

        }(queryParams, c, wg)

        go func() {
            wg.Wait()
            close(c)
        }()

    //DO THINGS



    }
```

Comment: An [HTTP 408](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408) is basically the remote host closing an idle connection. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code.

Comment: You have a normal error condition and decided to panic. You got a panic. What else to expect. It is perfectly acceptable of the server to respond with 408. Maybe the server answers more often with 408 if accessed concurrently? What's wrong with your code is other stuff like new Clients for each request and unhandled errors.

Comment: Yea I expected panic from panic() :P . Just wanted to know in which way I could handle it. Thanks for the feedback, i'll take care of the wrong things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cant afford the application to terminate.

Then do not panic but handle the 408, e.g. by retrying or returning an error upstream.